# Reload Flexcard with data change in fly out Omniscript

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, salesforce-service-cloud, omnis-studio-10

I am using Omnistudio. The idea is to add education records
Here is the architecture am following:
I have parent omniscript with a embedded LWCflex card which has “Add Education” button which opens up a flyout Omniscript to add education details and Integration Procedure is being called and a navigation action with pub sub enabled and vlocEvents is passed as a key with name of Parent Flexcard name as a value
I have added event listener in parent Flexcard for card reload.
However new record is not being reflected on parent OS when flyout Omniscript closes.